# WCF service called from compact framework

Tags: wcf, compact-framework, wcf-client

I have been trying to follow [this](http://community.opennetcf.com/articles/cf/archive/2007/11/29/an-introduction-to-wcf-for-device-developers.aspx) article on communicating with a WCF service from a mobile device (using compact framework 3.5).  I have the service running on the desktop, and it tells me that it's running as:

```
http://localhost:1414/MyService.svc
```

I can see this in my client, but when I try to access it, I get this error:

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:1414/MyService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

So I did:

```
InnerException: {"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"}
```

I am running from the emulator, which the article states did not work - I therefore suspect that I have encountered the same issue.  So my question is, does anyone know why this issue may occur?

EDIT:

Just to clarify, this works fine when deployed to the device.  It's just the emulator that has the problem.

EDIT:

Thanks to @Shiraz Bhaiji I have made some progress with this now, but am now getting the error returned:

```
CFFaultException
```

This seems to be the only error information I can get, and it's caused by the call:

```
MyServiceServiceClient client = new MyServiceServiceClient(binding, endpoint);    
returnString = client.MyFunc1();
```

I have changed the endpoint to reference my I.P. address directly as follows (the WCF service is running on my PC at the minute):

```
Binding binding = MyServiceServiceClient.CreateDefaultBinding();
string remoteAddress = MyServiceServiceClient.EndpointAddress.Uri.ToString();
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://1.1.1.1/MyService/MyService.svc");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Eric Schneider's answer on this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxcompact/thread/b5be4c83-40ca-423b-9068-8614779fed5f

Connect to the server using the IP address.

Comment: I hate linked answers. Now, the MSDN site listed above isn't there anymore. I could have used this information in my Windows Mobile WCF project.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `localhost` to the actual name of your computer.

Comment: Also, if you're running in the Visual Studio Development Server, don't. Use IIS.

Comment: Why not use VS Development Server?

Comment: I tried both of these suggestions with no success.  I can contact the service using a standard .net client - it's only running the CF under an emulator that causes a problem

Comment: Sorry, I didn't actually notice the word "emulator" in your question. The Windows Mobile emulators are terrible for network connectivity.